# Ошибка при использовании в ActivityEventBus

Tags: android, activity, android-service, eventbus

Есть сервис

```
package com.example.my.myapplication;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;

public class MyService extends Service {

    Socket client = null;
    DataOutputStream dataToServerStream = null;
    DataInputStream dataFromServerStream = null;
    Boolean isConnected = false;

    ExecutorService es;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String dataToServer = intent.getStringExtra("dataToServer");
        //сервис может вызываться больше 1 раза, поэту проверяем был ли клиент уже подключен
        if (isConnected){
            try {
                //если клиент уже был подключен, то это попытка отправки данных на сервер
                byte[] buf = dataToServer.getBytes("UTF-8");
                dataToServerStream.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            //если клиент еще не подключался - то подключаемся
            MyRun mr = new MyRun(startId, dataToServer);
            es.execute(mr);
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    //класс подключения к серверу
    class MyRun implements Runnable {

        String dataToServer;
        int startId;

        public MyRun(int startId, String dataToServer) {
            this.dataToServer = dataToServer;
            this.startId = startId;
        }

        public void run() {
            //подключение к серверу
            try {
                client = new Socket("193.1**.1*.2*", 1605);
                dataToServerStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                dataFromServerStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                isConnected = true;
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Got an IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            //стартуем асинктаск приема данных с сервера
            GetDataFromServer GetData = new GetDataFromServer();
            GetData.execute();
        }
    }

    //асинктаск приема данных с сервера
    class GetDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //чтение данных с сервера
            while (true) {
                try {
                    //String r = "";
                    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[5 * 1024];
                    //int read = 0;
                    int read = dataFromServerStream.read(readBuffer);
                    if (read != -1) {
                        byte[] readData = new byte[read];
                        System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, readData, 0, read);
                        try {
                            String r = new String(readData, "UTF-8");
                            publishProgress(r);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        //здесь мы отправляем данные в активити
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {


            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent(values[0]));


        }
    }
}
```

и код в активити

```
package com.example.my.myapplication;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText EditTextLogin;
    EditText EditTextPassword;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditTextLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLogin);
        EditTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        // создаем Intent для вызова сервиса
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        // стартуем сервис
        startService(intent);

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    //нажатие кнопки входа
    public void onClickEnter(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        String dataToServer = EditTextLogin.getText().toString();
        intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class).putExtra("dataToServer", dataToServer);
        startService(intent);
    }


    // В этом методе-колбэке мы получаем наши данные
    // (объект `event` типа класса-модели MessageEvent)
    public void onEvent(MessageEvent event){
        // извлекаем из модели отправленную строку: event.message = "Hello everyone!"
       EditTextLogin.setText(event.message);
    }



}
```

MessageEvent

```
package com.example.my.myapplication;

public class MessageEvent {
    public final String message;

    public MessageEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

суть такая. при старте активити запускается сервис. в сервисе происходит подключение к серверу, далее слушаем ответы от сервера. в активити при нажатии на кнопку, отправляем данные серверу. но при запуске приложения оно вылетает с ошибкой

> Caused by: org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.example.my.myapplication.MainActivity and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation

в строке

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей ошибке дословно сказано, что у вас в активити нема публичного метода с аннотацией `@Subscribe`. Просто добавьте эту аннотацию методу `onEvent`